# Pandas. Корректно ли сделал решения?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть дата-фрейм (картинка со структурой во вложении)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]:

```
df.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 32561 entries, 0 to 32560
Data columns (total 15 columns):
Column Non-Null Count Dtype
--- ------ -------------- -----
0 age 32561 non-null int64

1 workclass 32561 non-null object

2 fnlwgt 32561 non-null int64

3 education 32561 non-null object

4 education-num 32561 non-null int64

5 marital-status 32561 non-null object

6 occupation 32561 non-null object

7 relationship 32561 non-null object

8 race 32561 non-null object

9 sex 32561 non-null object

10 capital-gain 32561 non-null int64

11 capital-loss 32561 non-null int64

12 hours-per-week 32561 non-null int64

13 native-country 32561 non-null object

14 salary 32561 non-null object

dtypes: int64(6), object(9)
```

Вот так я решал ( или подсмотрел ) решения заданий:

- **Шаг 1**. Загрузить данные с файла расширения csv (adult.data.csv) -

Изучить содержание признаков

```
df.head()
```

Определить количество строк, колонок

```
df.shape
```

- **Шаг 2**. Провести очистку данных -

Выполнить проверку на пустые значения
(*достаточно ли этого?*)

```
df.isnull().sum()
```

Определить типы данных

```
df.info()
```

Поиск дубликатов
( *возможно ли задать больше подробностей?* )

```
df.duplicated().sum()
```

Поиск аномалий
( *хотелось бы вывести более полную информацию* )

```
for i in df.columns:
    print(i)
    print(df[i].unique(), '\n')
```

- **Шаг 3**. С помощью библиотеки Pandas ответить на несколько вопросов по данным набора Adult по доходу населения, каждый объект которого содержит социальные характеристики некоторого человека (возраст, пол, профессиональная деятельность и т.п.) -

1. Сколько неженатых граждан (признак relationship = Unmarried) представлено в этом наборе данных?
   ( *не уверен, что это полное решение* )

```
df[df['marital-status'] == 'Never-married']['marital-status'].value_counts()
```

2. Каков средний возраст (признак age ) женщин (признак sex = Female)),
   которые зарабатывают много? ( признак salary = >50K)
   ( решение кажется логичное, но получаю: nan )

```
df[(df['sex'] == 'female') & (df['salary'] == '>50K')]['age'].mean()
```

3. Какое наибольшее количество часов человек работает в неделю? (признак hours-per-week)

```
df['hours-per-week'].describe()['max']
```

4. Сколько граждан много зарабатывают (признак salary = >50K),
   которые закончили 9 классов? (признак education = 9th)

```
df[(df['education'] == '9th') & (df['salary'] == '>50K')]['salary'].value_counts()
```

5. Посчитайте среднее время работы (признак hours-per-week)
   зарабатывающих мало и много (признак salary).

```
df.pivot_table( ["hours-per-week"], ["salary"], aggfunc="mean", ).head()
```

- **Шаг 4**. Написать код для записи результатов в файл с разделителями (csv) -

```
df.to_csv('my_written_file.csv ', sep=',')
```

---

Пожалуйста, проверьте и поправьте решения.

Не хватает четкости понимания
и хотелось оформить выводы как-то более красиво и полнее - тут у меня ступор.

Мой уровень "начинающий" и многие моменты "плывут".

Не могу найти русскоязычной литературы или онлайн-ресурсы где бы это всё последовательно разжевывалось от простого к сложному по всем темам (особенно изложенным выше).

Comment: Наверное с этой просьбой лучше обратиться к преподавателю.

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут явных прямо ошибок может и нет, но есть некоторые непонятки.

- Например, вопрос "что такое аномалии" - он не тривиальный. Вот тот `value_counts`, который вы мне кажется не везде к месту применяете, как-раз для выявления аномалий мог бы и пригодиться, но только для категориальных признаков. Те категориальные значения, доля которых мала (долю можно взять через параметр `normalized=True`) - могут быть аномалиями. А вот для непрерывных значений может быть нужно уже смотреть квантили или ещё какие-то статистики и что там выходит за рамки этих статистик, там просто уникальными значениями можно не обойтись.
- Вообще `mean` по умолчанию значения `NA` не должен учитывать, значит скорее всего у вас получилась пустая выборка, если на выходе `NA`. Значит нужно проверять оба условия по отдельности и смотреть, работают они или нет, может что-то напутано (например, в строке `>50K` может быть русская буква `K`, а может быть английская). Если по отдельности они работают, значит возможно у вас просто нет таких строк в датасете, где выполняются оба условия вместе.
- Там, где нужно взять просто количество одинаковых значений и значение одно, там излишне использовать `.value_counts()`, а можно взять `.shape[0]`, например.

Ну и по мелочи ещё что-то было, без самих данных, довольно сложно так "на пальцах" анализировать код.